# Link different folders to different hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I'm using a fusion set-up for new computers at work (e.g. 128GB SSD with a 1TB HDD). The SSD is meant to be for the user profile only, and all applications should be installed on the HDD. However, many staff just dump all their data on 'Desktop' or 'Documents', filling up the SSD. Is there a way to somehow redirect data from folders such as 'Desktop' and 'Documents' to the HDD, or possibly to keep the OS on the SSD but move a few user profile folders to the HDD?
Thanks!
Kyan

Comment: what OS/version of windows?

Comment: This question doesn't work without revealing what Operating System (and version) is being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the entire user profile is one option. This is most easily done by [changing the default profile location in the registry](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7) and then creating a new user for day-to-day use (you can even delete the old one afterward, if you want). You can move an established user profile, instead, but it's a mess; you have to find every reference in the registry to your old profile location and change it. A better option is to [move your profile (or even the entire Users folder) while the OS is offline, and then create a directory junction or symbolic link (symlink)](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-change-user-profile-location-in-windows-8-without-registry-hack/) from `C:\Users` (or `C:\Users\<username>`) to the new location. This technique should also work pre-Win8 (despite the URL); symlinks were introduced in Vista, and junctions are even older (although they used to be more of a pain to create, before the `mklink` command arrived with Vista).

Note that both of these approaches are, essentially, unsupported. You may find yourself unable to do things like install service packs or in-place upgrades of Windows if you do this - I ran into this problem back on a Vista machine and don't know if it's been fixed yet - and could experience other problems too. It also won't solve the problem of programs that install without letting you choose a location, but don't install to your user profile. Finally, there's an argument for putting at least the core parts of your profile - your user registry and system settings files - on the boot disk. Not only will this be faster (if your boot disk is an SSD and your data disk isn't), it means your profile doesn't become unusable if your data disk dies or gets removed.

To support this idea of "critical profile stuff on the boot drive, data elsewhere", Windows has (for many versions now, not sure exactly when it started) allowed you to change the locations of most of your personal data directories. In essence, the Desktop/Documents/Downloads/Music/Pictures/Videos directories have been *virtual* locations for some time now (for example, XP->Vista changed "My Documents" to "Documents" when viewed in Explorer, but the underlying file system name did *not* change if you did an in-place upgrade). Open Windows Explorer, go to your user profile, and right-click one of your virtual directories. Open `Properties` and go to the "Location" tab. Click `Move...` and select the directory (after creating it, if needed) on your data drive where you want the contents of that virtual directory to reside. Windows will offer to move everything from the current "real" directory to the new one. Thereafter, anything that tries to install to "your Documents folder" will actually install under the new location (though, of course, anything that simply hard-codes a path like `%USER_PROFILE%\Documents\StupidApp_Stuff` without going through the shell APIs will not see this change). Doesn't solve the "program just puts itself wherever it wants without asking you" problem, either... but at least this approach is supported by Microsoft, and keeps your data (documents, music, saved games, whatever) separate from your profile settings (user registry, application data, etc.).

To deal with the case of programs rudely putting themselves (or their files) where they are not wanted, I once again recommend symlinks. Move the offending file or directory (while the relevant program is not running, of course) to your data drive, then replace its original location with a symlink to the new location (using `mklink`). For example, if `C:\ProgramData\RudeApp` is taking up tens of gigabytes and wasting your SSD's space, you can try running the following commands (this assumes using CMD, not Powershell or another shell, and assumes you don't already have a `D:\ProgramData` directory):

```
md D:\ProgramData
xcopy /e /k /o /h C:\ProgramData\RudeApp D:\ProgramData\RudeApp\
rd /s C:\ProgramData\RudeApp
mklink /d C:\ProgramData\RudeApp D:\ProgramData\RudeApp
```

What this does is, in order:

1. Create the ProgramData directory on your D: drive (of course, ProgramData is hidden and has some tricky ACLs on the C: drive, so you might want to use `xcopy /k /o /h C:\ProgramData D:\ProgramData` instead to get all that metadata, though this will also copy any files directly under ProgramData)
2. Copy all files in the original C:\ProgramData\RudeApp directory to a new directory (D:\ProgramData\RudeApp) on your data drive. This copy is recursive (it will copy subdirectories too), and preserves file security and attributes.
3. Delete the original C:\ProgramData\RudeApp directory. You can rename it instead of deleting it if you want to make sure everything works right, then delete it afterward.
4. Creates a directory symbolic link at C:\ProgramData\RudeApp - the location where the app will expect to find its files - that points to the new location (D:\ProgramData\RudeApp). Programs, including Windows Explorer, will see the link as though it's a directory on C:, but it's merely a pointer (in NTFS-ese, a "reparse point") to a directory on D:. The pointer takes up only a trivial amount of space on C:.

You can safely delete symlinks without affecting the linked-to files or directories. Renaming the symlink is also safe (though stuff that was looking for it will think that you removed the folder). Renaming or moving a *linked-to* file or directory is *not* safe; this will break the link and you'll need to delete it and re-create it pointing to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

junctions, hard links, etc

You will need to make the destination folder and copy the files in there in before mklink /j

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

```
mklink /j Documents j:\Documents
mklink /?
```

From the website **developers tidbits** this article explains it.
**windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links**

[source material](https://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/)

> A symbolic link is like a shortcut but instead of being saved as a
>   file it is registered to the hard drive partition. It does not use any
>   disk space and all programs recognise both the link and the target. A
>   symbolic link can point to any file or folder either locally on the
>   computer or over a network using a SMB path.
>
> A file hard link is a little different and can not be used over
>   multiple partitions meaning you can not have a link on drive C:
>   pointing to a file on drive D:. A file hard link points to and
>   duplicates a target as a mirrored copy but the copy does not use any
>   additional space on the hard drive partition. So 2 hard links that
>   mirrored a 1 GB file would  in total only use 1 GB on the partition
>   rather than 3 GB. Importantly if either the hard links or the target
>   are deleted the other links retain the data. Changes to the content of
>   either the target or the links automatically propagate to all other
>   items.
>
> A junction behaves like a hard link for directories but unlike file
>   hard links you can create junctions that span multiple partitions.
>   Again a directory junction and its content is stored on the hard drive
>   partition but they do not use any additional space. Any changes to the
>   content within either the target or the links will automatically
>   propagate except where the target directory is deleted or renamed. In
>   that case all links that point to the target will break and linger on
>   the partition.

Comment: Could you expand this answer a bit? What will a junction do, what will a hard link do, how will this solve his issue?

Comment: @SimonSheehan really, what do they do? As far as this person is concern they do exactly what he wants.  Link a folder to a different hard drive.

Comment: This answer appears very low quality when you display it like this.

Comment: You've just copied directly without attribution. It also doesn't actually answer the users question.

Comment: @MichaelFrank  I provided a link to the original material as attribution.  Also mklink /j  does exactly what the user wants.

Comment: @cybernard Perhaps you should read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)